# Dual passports in Saudi Arabia

Tags: dual-nationality, saudi-arabia, cyprus, yemeni-citizens, cypriot-citizens

I'm Yemeni, living in Saudi Arabia, where I have permanent residency.  I have passport from two countries, Yemen and Cyprus. The information used in the Saudi immigration system is from my Yemeni passport. The Yemeni passport, unlike the Cypriot one, does not allow me to travel to many countries without a visa.

If I want to use my Cypriot passport to travel, do I also have to show my Yemeni passport? What passport should I show at the airport in Saudi Arabia? When I'm able to enter a country visa-free with my Cypriot passport, do I also have to get a visa in my Yemeni passport?

Comment: @GregHewgill if we rephrase this question as "will I get in trouble if I acknowledge to the Saudi authorities that I also hold a Cypriot passport," which is essentially what it's asking, then it is not actually a duplicate.

Comment: @phoog Following the steps in the proposed duplicate means that OP does not need to "acknowledge" to Saudi authorities that they're a dual citizen.  I also doubt the Saudis would care, since he's not a Saudi citizen and Saudi-Cypriot relations are fine.  (But that's speculative.)